# SPFX OnChange Event

Tags: spfx-webparts, dropdown

I am pretty new to the framework. I am trying to change the viewmodel based on the change of the property pane dropdown. I am trying to access the onchange event however that doesnt see to exist out of the box. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every time you change a property in the web part property pane, SharePoint Framework calls the web part `render` method, where you can choose to update the view and repaint the web part. If you want, you can distinguish between the initial render and follow-up renders caused by changes to properties by checking the value of the `renderedOnce` property, like in here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/366c28a57753ad410a1b50376dd5738186bbb6ed/samples/angular-todo/src/webparts/toDo/ToDoWebPart.ts#L19

What JavaScript library are you using? There are different ways how your code can respond to property changes: in React for example it's quite easy as the whole component tree is rerendered. In AngularJS for example, you have to push it from the web part to the application using events.

Answer (score 0):

An `onchange` event does not exist. However, an "on validating" (officially called `ongeterrormessage`) does, and this event fires on every change.

Refer [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/validate-web-part-property-values)